# How to solve $\frac{d}{dx}\int_x^{x^3} \sin^3(t) \,dt $

Tags: derivatives

How would I find the derivative for this equation?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not an equation.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you do **don't do the integral!**

$$\int_x^{x^3}\sin^3 t\,dt=g(x^3)-g(x)$$
where $$g(y)=\int_0^y \sin^3 t\,dt.$$
Then $g'(y)=\sin^3 y$. This allows you to differentiate
$g(x^3)-g(x)$ painlessly.

Comment: You Forgot about the $dt$ i guess ?

Answer (score 0):

Using Newton theorem it's simply
$$\sin^3(x^3).3x^2-\sin^3(x)$$

Note:

$$\frac{d(\int_a^bf(x).dx)}{dx}=f(b).db-f(a).da$$

Comment: What? Are you referring to the Chain Rule and the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus? You are using fairly non-standard notation here

Comment: Yes that only. I'm a bit unfamiliar about the standard one. Could you please edit? @BrevanEllefsen